# Label loop crashes seemingly without reason

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, set, directory, mkdir

Don't ask me why, but I try to create a 5-digit code consisting of folders.
The following code seemed promising, however at folder 0\0\1\0 it crashes: it returns that 0\0\1\0\%E% already exists.
Definition for %E% can be found in the code.

```
@echo off
set A=0
set B=0
set C=0
set D=0
set E=-1

:A

set /a E=E+1
if %E%==10 (set E=0 && set /a D=D+1)
if %D%==10 (set D=0 && set /a C=C+1)
if %C%==10 (set C=0 && set /a B=B+1)
if %B%==10 (set B=0 && set /a A=A+1)
if %A%==10 goto B
mkdir %A%\%B%\%C%\%D%\%E%
REM pause to get the error
goto A

:B
echo 111.111 folders have been made
pause
exit
```

Looking for a fix or a new version alltogether.

Comment: Did the fix in my answer below work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Batch file below is an *equivalent*, but simpler solution:

```
@echo off

set ABCDE=99999

:loop
   set /A ABCDE+=1
   mkdir %ABCDE:~1,1%\%ABCDE:~2,1%\%ABCDE:~3,1%\%ABCDE:~4,1%\%ABCDE:~5,1%
if %ABCDE% neq 199999 goto loop

echo 111.111 folders have been made
pause
```

Comment: I had no clue what mkdir `%ABCDE:~1,1%` ment, but did some testing and it appears that `~1` takes the second character and `,1` defines the amount of numbers used. Great solution :)

Comment: Yes. You may read the same explanation if you type `set /?` at the command-prompt. **`;)`**

Answer (score 2):

@JosefStyons identified the core problem in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33507018/5047996): there are spaces after the numerical digits in the values; but this is actually true for *all* variables except `A`.
This is caused by the `if` command lines -- let us pick one as an example:

```
if %E%==10 (set E=0 && set /a D=D+1)
```

The reason for the problem is the *space* after the `set E=0` command. It is also the same for the other `if` lines of course.

To solve that issue, you could do either:

```
if %E%==10 (set "E=0" && set /a D=D+1)
```

or:

```
if %E%==10 ((set E=0) && set /a D=D+1)
```

or even (but with degraded legibility):

```
if %E%==10 (set E=0&& set /a D=D+1)
```

The problem does not exist for `set /A` instances as they treat values as numeric ones, whereas `set` commands without the `/A` switch treat values as strings.

Comment: Now I am curious, why does the space only affect the fourth level and not the second or third?

Comment: It affects _all_ but the first, but _only_ in case the `if` statement is executed and a number is reset to `0`; the first level (`A`) is _not_ affected, because there is no related `set A=0 && ...` statement...

Comment: Ha! I'm glad you found the issue, trying to find that space was really making my head hurt yesterday, but there it was right in front of me...

Answer (score 1):

Your %D% is getting a trailing space after the first iteration, so the MKDIR statements end up like this about 100 folders in (note the spaces):

```
...
mkdir 0\0\0\9\7
mkdir 0\0\0\9\8
mkdir 0\0\0\9\9
mkdir 0\0\1\0 \0 <--space
mkdir 0\0\1\0 \1 <--space
mkdir 0\0\1\0 \2 <--space
mkdir 0\0\1\0 \3 <--space
mkdir 0\0\1\0 \4 <--space
mkdir 0\0\1\0 \5 <--space
mkdir 0\0\1\0 \6 <--space
mkdir 0\0\1\0 \7 <--space
mkdir 0\0\1\0 \8 <--space
mkdir 0\0\1\0 \9 <--space
mkdir 0\0\1\1\0 
mkdir 0\0\1\1\1
mkdir 0\0\1\1\2
mkdir 0\0\1\1\3
...
```

The evaluation stops at the space, and indeed "0\0\1\0" does already exist at that point.

I honestly don't know why that's only happening to D, and not the other variables.  I'm probably missing something obvious.

You can suppress the problem by adding this line just before the "mkdir", however:

```
if "%D%"=="0 " set D=0
```

On another note, a helpful way to debug batch files like this one is to remove the "pause" statements, put an "echo" in front of the "mkdir", then just redirect the output to a file.  You can look at the output and see what mkdir statements it **would** have executed.

Comment: The problem persists for _all_ variables `B` to `E`, but the space in `E` is ignored by `mkdir` as it is appended at the end of the path; `D` is the first variable where the problem is visible because it increments 10 times more often than `C`, which in turn increments 10 times faster than `B`, etc.; `A` is not affected as there is no string assignment (`set` without the `/A` switch)...

Comment: @JosephStyons The problem indeed is the space. `if "%D%"=="0 " set D=0` works, but `if %D%==10 (set "D=0" && set /a C=C+1)` is more elegant.
I love your tip about echoing mkdir btw :) Problem is `echo mkdir %A%\%B%\%C%\%D%\%E%>filename.txt` would constantly overwrite, or if you take %filename% it would make 111.111 txt files. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: @Iterniam: To overcome the 'multiple files' issue, leave it as just 
`echo mkdir %A%\%B%\%C%\%D%\%E%` in the batch file itself.  Then instead of just double-clicking the batch file to execute it, execute it from the command prompt with a redirect, as in `c:\my_batch_file.bat>c:\output.txt`.  That will redirect all of the output to a single file.

Comment: @JosephStyons It works :) pretty cool watching the file grow :P. Figured that `echo "insetcommandhere">>filename.extension"` adds the echo to the next line in the file, might come in usefull if you dont want every output to be in the text document.